# Разработка форм для работы с MySQL на Python

Tags: html, mysql, python

Какой технологией воспользоваться для создания визуальных форм для внесения и просмотра записей в СУБД MySQL? Функционал должен быть на уровне форм MS Access. Основной критерий - простота освоения, т.к. уровень знаний python'a хромает. Наилучший вариант - html формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать Flask + Jinja2. В любом случае придется изучать, т.к. Python язык программирования, а не готовый инструмент, коим является MS Access.